# Compress pictures but getting "unknown compression method"

Tags: java, image, exception, compression, zip

I running a java chatgame client and it's loads the picture before showing it in the chat.

I did compress all pictures we've using on our chatgame via Yahoo Smush.it, but after it gets this error in Java Console:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: unknown compression method
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:147)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:344)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:246)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGFilterInputStream.read(PNGImageDecoder.java:810)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:221)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:346)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:246)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
```

But now i have opened every picture in photoshop and saved again, but it take diskplace for over 20MB, so my question is:

How can i compress all my images correctly, without getting conflict with java compression?
Any sites?

Comment: Welcome to SO.post some related source code..

Comment: *"but it take diskplace for over 20MB.."*  It seems as though the entire use of images needs to be rethought.